# Error: "attribute value must be constant". Can I constract a constant from an enum at compile time?

Tags: java, enums, annotations, constants

The following code works fine, where PROCESS_UPDATES is a constant.

```
    public static final String PROCESS_UPDATES = "ProcessUpdates";
    public static final String PROCESS_UPDATES = "ProcessSnapshots";
    // etc....

    @Produce(uri = "seda:" + MyClass.PROCESS_UPDATES)
    protected ProducerTemplate processUpdatesTemplate;
```

However to avoid a billion constant strings all over the place, I was experimenting with an enum design pattern.

```
    public enum Route { ProcessUpdates, ProcessSnapshots }
```

In most circumstances, I can write `"seda:" + Route.ProcessSnapshots` and it looks much neater.

However my trusty test code now fails, because the uri in the annotation must be constant.

```
    @Produce(uri = "seda:" + MyClass.Route.ProcessUpdates)    // compiler error
    protected ProducerTemplate processUpdatesTemplate;
```

Error: `Attribute value must be constant`.

The thing is, that `Route.ProcessUpdates.toString()` kind of "is" a constant, but the compiler doesn't see it that way.

I head a read [about constants and annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510319/constants-and-annotation) but I didn't see any answer.

So is there a nice way to construct a constant String from an enum at compile-time in java?

Thanks for any tips.
vikingsteve

Comment: This posting might be of some use (String Literals in Java Enums):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667243/using-enum-values-as-string-literals

Comment: Thanks, however none of the solutions there offer a "constant" value, as far as I can see, e.g. `MyClass.Route.ProcessSnapshots.name()` is not a constant (still get the error)

Comment: There is no way to make an Enum a "constant".  However, you can add the ability to turn an Enum into a String value, which could be made `final`.  I think this is a better approach than the old `public static final` as it's more "portable", but that's only my opinion.

Comment: @CodeChimp do you mean via a string argument to the enum constructor? Otherwise could you please elaborate.

Comment: From your example, you are trying to concatenate a String using a constant.  You could use the process in the linked post, creating an entry for `PROCESS_UPDATES("ProcessUpdates")` and `PROCESS_SNAPSHOTS("ProcessSnapshots")`, which sets some variable (in the example they use `name`, but it can be called whatever), then use the same overwritten `toString()` in the example.  Then you would have an Enum that would toString to the one you wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to this.

As far as I can see, it's not possible.

I needed to use string constants... `public static final String XYZ = "Xyz";` - etc.